# New string from multiple strings with most common words

Tags: php, string

I am trying to create a new string from multiple strings using the most common words between these strings. For example:

```
$string[0] = 'Apple iPhone 4S 16GB Locked to Orange';
$string[1] = 'iPhone 4S 16GB boxed new';
$string[2] = 'iPhone 4S 16GB unlocked brand new';
$string[3] = 'Apple iPhone 16GB 4S Special Offer';
$string[4] = 'Apple iPhone 4S Sim Free';

## The new string should be:

$new_string = 'Apple iPhone 4S 16GB';
```

There could be hundreds of original strings, or just 2...

I don't have a clue where to start with this, any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Apple appears 3 times, iPhone appears 5 times, 4S appears 5 times, 16GB appears 4 times. What do you mean by "the most common words" ?

Comment: I'm just as clueless as you on this but wouldn't a good start be to chop up the strings so you can perform queries on individual words on the strings?

Comment: I don't think you've thought this through thoroughly, but just so you get some practice: use `preg_split('/\b+/m',$aString)` and `array_intersect` to determine what words occur in other strings...

Comment: @Ninsuo: Good question, I guess the word count that would determine whether it is put in the new string would need to be set somehow based on the amount of original strings. I think you can see what I am trying to accomplish though, If a human was given the task to write a common shorter title using the strings above, you would get the $new_string I mention above..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
$string = array();
$string[0] = 'Apple iPhone 4S 16GB Locked to Orange';
$string[1] = 'iPhone 4S 16GB boxed new';
$string[2] = 'iPhone 4S 16GB unlocked brand new';
$string[3] = 'Apple iPhone 16GB 4S Special Offer';
$string[4] = 'Apple iPhone 4S Sim Free';

print(getCommon($string));
```

Output

```
Apple iPhone 4S 16GB
```

Function Used

```
function getCommon($array,$occurance = 3)
{
    $array = array_reduce($array, function($a,$b) { $a = array_merge($a,explode(" ", $b)); return $a; },array());
    return implode(" ",array_keys(array_filter(array_count_values($array),function($var)use($occurance) {return $var > $occurance ;})));
}
```

[See Live DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/xMfYcq)

Comment: I think this is absolutely spot on and exactly what I needed. I am going to except this answer. Thanks to Peehaa though, your answer gave me the count of words but wasn't a complete working answer. @Baba, would you mind explaining what is going on in your code, I like to understand as much as I like to cut&paste :) Also do you have suggestions for how best to determine the occurance to use.. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should get you started:

```
function getWordCount($someArray)
{
    $wordList = array();
    foreach($someArray as $item) {
        $wordList = array_merge($wordList, explode(' ', $item));
    }

    $result = array_count_values($wordList);
    arsort($result);

    return $result;
}
```

Note I explode based on space character and this doesn't take into account punctuation etc like `.` or `,`. If you want to account for this you should use some simple regex pattern to get the words in the string according to your requirement.

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/IuAc2s

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it

```
$min_times_present = 3;
$words  = array();
foreach ($string as $str) {
  $words_string = preg_split('/\s+/', $str, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
  foreach ($words_string as $word) {
    $words[$word] = (isset($words[$word])) ? $words[$word]+1 : 1;
  }
}
$result_arr = array_filter($words, function($value) use ($min_times_present) {
  return ($value >= $min_times_present);
});
arsort($result_arr, SORT_NUMERIC);
$result_str = implode(' ', array_keys($result_arr));
```

Comment: Thanks for this, is there any advantage to doing it this way?

Comment: @superphonic Compared to the others, I don't think so. But you could benchmark the different methods posted here, using different combinations of strings and large quantities of strings. Use the one which is more robust.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and my solution was to merge all the phrases in one array of words then get the words with the highest number of occurences :

```
$string = array();
$string[0] = 'Apple iPhone 4S 16GB Locked to Orange';
$string[1] = 'iPhone 4S 16GB boxed new';
$string[2] = 'iPhone 4S 16GB unlocked brand new';
$string[3] = 'Apple iPhone 16GB 4S Special Offer';
$string[4] = 'Apple iPhone 4S Sim Free';
$words=array();
for($i=0;$i<count($string);$i++){
    $words = array_merge($words,str_word_count($string[$i],1));
}

$instances = array_count_values($words);
arsort($instances);
$instances = array_slice($instances,0,5);
foreach($instances as $word=>$count){
    echo $word.' ';
}
    // Outputs "iPhone S GB Apple new"
```

The problem with this method is that if a words appears several times in the same string its number of occurences will be increased.